# VirtualBox Host-Only Adapter looks like Ethernet 3

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ethernet, host-only

I have a problem in my network and sharing center. I allowed windows updates and got an update. Then I faced the problem. My VirtualBox Host-Only Adapter looks like "Ethernet 3" on my network and sharing center. When I try to change its IPv4 address to 172.16.3.1, it gives the warning "This IP address is already assigned to the VirtualBox Host Only Ethernet Adapter adapter on the computer." I reinstalled VirtualBox to fix the problem, but there is no change. It still gives the same warning.

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-09
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Host Only is an isolated machine.  Change your Virtual Machine network type to NAT (works fine) or Bridged (if you want the machine on the same subnet as your router).

NAT is likely the best choice. I am using NAT on this VM I am posting on, and updates work fine.